# Static Variable to assign to ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, variables, static, threadpoolexecutor

I am try to assign static variable as a parameter for ThreadPoolExecutor.

```
Public class MyClass{

   private static final int corePoolSize;
   static{
      corePoolSize= 30;
   }

   private static ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,threadFactory)

 ...
}
```

Above Line is failing.

Below one is no issue, if I pass value directly to threadpollexecutor

```
private static ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(30, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,threadFactory)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are getting

Comment: Can not reproduce, please include the whole error message with the stacktrace into your question, see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: issue seams like different, so closing this ticket.

Comment: not reproducible so closing this ticket